# Invisible bodies?

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x, rigid-bodies

In my game I have about 20 blocks on which the character can walk. Each block has a body and the character has a body too.

Sometimes when my character walks, it is blocked by something. When this happens I can "delete" the invisible wall by walking to the other side a bit and then go back.

as far as I know I'm doing nothing wrong. Here's the code I use to draw blocks/character:

character:

```
    b2BodyDef raymanBodyDef;


    raymanBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    raymanBodyDef.position.Set(winsize.width/2/PTM_RATIO, winsize.height/2/PTM_RATIO);


    raymanBody = world->CreateBody(&raymanBodyDef);
    bodyUserData *bud = new bodyUserData;
    bud->bodytype = 1;
    bud->sprite = rayman;
    raymanBody->SetUserData(bud);

    b2PolygonShape raymanShape;
    raymanShape.SetAsBox(16.5/ PTM_RATIO, 32.5/PTM_RATIO);



    b2FixtureDef raymanShapeDef;
    raymanShapeDef.shape = &raymanShape;
    raymanShapeDef.density = 10.0f;
    raymanShapeDef.friction = 0.0f;
    raymanShapeDef.restitution = 0;
    raymanBody->SetFixedRotation(true);
    raymanBody->CreateFixture(&raymanShapeDef);
```

Block:

```
Block *b = new Block(40, 125);
this->addChild(b->sprite);
blocks.push_back(b);
b2Body *blockbody;
    for(int i = 0; i<blocks.size();i++)
    {
        cocos2d::CCLog("%d", i);
        b2BodyDef def = blocks[i]->blockbodydef;
        bodyUserData *bud2 = new bodyUserData;
        bud2->bodytype = 3;
        bud2->sprite = blocks[i]->sprite;
        bud2->canDelete = false;

        blockbody = world->CreateBody(&def);
        blockbody->SetUserData(bud2);


        blockbody->CreateFixture(&blocks[i]->blockshapedef);
    }
```

Block constructor:

```
Block::Block(float x, float y)
{
sprite = cocos2d::CCSprite::create("Block.png", cocos2d::CCRect(0,0,50,50));
sprite->setPosition(ccp(x,y));

blockbodydef.type = b2_kinematicBody;
blockbodydef.position.Set(x/PTM_RATIO,y/PTM_RATIO);
//blockbodydef.userData = sprite;



blockPoly.SetAsBox(50/PTM_RATIO , 50/ PTM_RATIO);

blockshapedef.shape = &blockPoly;
blockshapedef.density = 2.0f;
blockshapedef.friction = 0.0f;
blockshapedef.restitution = 0.0f;
}
```

the character sprite is 33x65 and the block sprite is 50x50.

Comment: unable to understand what is problem

Comment: What does the debug draw display show you? Is this the typical situation where the player gets stuck on interior edges in the ground? If so, this is mentioned in the manual and there are discussions about it all over the net. http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=7917 http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8409 http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/ghost-vertices